# How to get Regex for only contact number through web-scraping by eliminating the preceding Pin code number?

Tags: regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern cp1 =Pattern.compile("(\\(?\\+?\\d{1,3}\\)?[\\s-]+)?\\(?\\d{1,3}\\)?[\\s-]+\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{2}[\\s-]?\\d{2,}");
    Set<String> contacts = new HashSet<String>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ejrsearch.com/contact-us.html").ignoreHttpErrors(true).userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(0).get();
    Elements doc1 = doc.select("body");
    Matcher matcherc = cp1.matcher(doc1.text());
    while (matcherc.find()) {contacts.add(matcherc.group());}
    System.out.println("Contacts:"+contacts);}}
```

#### In `doc1.text()`

> Menu Contact Us We Want to Hear from You! If you are looking for your
> next position or for that “high performance” player that can help
> deliver for you please contact us. EJR Search Partners 1440 Broadway
> 23rd floor NY NY 10018 212-410-4141 info@ejrsearch.com Copyright 2011,
> EJR Search. All rights reserved.

Actually, Address is
EJR Search Partners 1440 Broadway 23rd floor NY NY 10018
212-410-4141

#### Output:

> Contacts:[018 212-410-4141].

But I want only the contact number by avoiding pin code.

Help me out in fixing this issue by modifying the existing pattern only.Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: this isn't really a java issue, it's a regex one. ought tag that appropriately

Comment: Posts with multiple questions are less likely to be answered, you should focus on a specific point.

Comment: To solve just this case is simple: ^[\d-]+

Comment: @Teja But before you edited the question, you were trying to solve it with some other conditions also I guess.

Comment: Pincode is 6 digits mostly. If your pincode is on new line then maybe you can use this: ^[\d-]{8,}

Comment: Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AiPdzC/1

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi thanks for you response. But I need to satisfy some more patterns also.The regex I mentioned meets my needs, except the pin code attachment . Can you make this possible by modifying the above pattern.

Comment: go here > http://regexr.com/ > Go to community in the sidebar and find different Phone number match regexes. One might match for you.

Comment: @Teja If you are trying to match only the phone number given in doc1.text() then see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General Regex for matching phone numbers in different format:

```
(\(?\+?\d{1,3}\)?[\s-]+)?\(?\d{1,3}\)?[\s-]+\d{3}[\s-]?\d{2}[\s-]?\d{2,}
```

Regex for matching the phone number in the document provided in the question:

```
[0-9-]{8,}
```

Comment: I tried like this.

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern cp1 =Pattern.compile("(\\(?\\+?\\d{1,3}\\)?[\\s-]+)?\\(?\\d{1,3}\\)?[\\s-]+\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{2}[\\s-]?\\d{2,}");
  Set<String> contacts = new HashSet<String>();
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ejrsearch.com/contact-us.html").ignoreHttpErrors(true).userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(0).get();
  Elements doc1 = doc.select("body");
  Matcher matcherc = cp1.matcher(doc1.text());
  while (matcherc.find()) {contacts.add(matcherc.group());}
  sop("Contacts:"+contacts);}}
Output:
Contacts:[018 212-410-4141]

Comment: Is this regex working for you on http://regexr.com/ Paste the html body in the body section on regexr.com and see if its matching everything. Then maybe we can see whats the implementation problem with java.

Comment: as you can see its matching everything here. Add all your cases also: https://regex101.com/r/AiPdzC/5

Comment: In background the body is coming like this " Menu Contact Us We Want to Hear from You! If you are looking for your next position or for that “high performance” player that can help deliver for you please contact us. EJR Search Partners 1440 Broadway 23rd floor NY NY 10018 212-410-4141 info@ejrsearch.com Copyright 2011, EJR Search. All rights reserved. "

Comment: Update the question and please provide all the exhaustive cases that you are trying to match.